# hardlink/symlink with mapped drives in Server 2003

Tags: network-shares, symbolic-link, windows-server-2003, hardlink, mapped-drive

I'm trying to create a hardlink on a Windows Server 2003 system using `fsutil hardlink create M:\docs L:\docs` but am receiving a message stating "The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume.  I imagine this is because both my source and destination drives are mapped network drives.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hardlinks only work within a single filesystem. Making hardlinks between separate filesystems (local or remote) is not supported.

This bit of info from Microsoft does a good job of explaining what can and can't be done with hard links:

> For example, in a system where C: and D: are local drives and Z: is a network drive mapped to \fred\share, the following references are permitted as a hard link:
>
> > C:\dira\ethel.txt linked to C:\dirb\dirc\lucy.txt
> >
> > D:\dir1\tinker.txt to D:\dir2\dirx\bell.txt
> >
> > C:\diry\bob.bak linked to C:\dir2\mina.txt
>
> The following are not:
>
> > C:\dira linked to C:\dirb
> >
> > C:\dira\ethel.txt linked to D:\dirb\lucy.txt
> >
> > C:\dira\ethel.txt linked to Z:\dirb\lucy.txt

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx